# Error loading module MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql, virtuemart, joomla-framework-1.x, jerror

I am facing a serious issue with Joomla version 1.7.

> MySQL server has gone away

I am using the shopping cart platform  Virtuemart. When I placed an order, the order confirmation message page is messed up and the order email has no product info etc.

The query causing trouble is:

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, m.module, m.position, m.content, m.showtitle, m.params, mm.menuid
FROM jos_modules AS m
LEFT JOIN jos_modules_menu AS mm ON mm.moduleid = m.id
LEFT JOIN jos_extensions AS e ON e.element = m.module AND e.client_id = m.client_id
WHERE m.published = 1
  AND e.enabled = 1
  AND (m.publish_up = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR m.publish_up <= '2014-05-21 05:56:53')
  AND (m.publish_down = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR m.publish_down >= '2014-05-21 05:56:53')
  AND m.access IN (1,1,2)
  AND m.client_id = 0
  AND (mm.menuid = 0 OR mm.menuid <= 0)
ORDER BY m.position, m.ordering
```

I already checked many sites and joomla forum almost every topic related to this issue is saying server mysql time out issue. [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&t=754609&view=previous) , [here](http://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=102866.0) and [this](http://www.corejoomla.com/forum/gps-tools/11568-getting-error-while-submit-track.html)

Last week the site was working fine.

Also I don't have privileges to update its version to the latest :(.

So basically should I report this issue to server admin or is there a coding solution?

**EDIT : SOLVED**

**This is issue is due to mysql query execution time, Server Admin able to increase the limit and the issue was fixed.**

Comment: Has the MySQL engine been updated on the server in the last week?

Comment: no its not updated I think , bcoz several versions of same projects running on the server, some have this issue and others works fine.

Comment: Try repairing the `#__modules table` and `#__extensions` via PhpMyAdmin

Comment: I checked both tables on working DB and error DB but both are same , Also the error generating site have a VM shopper group error too. any guess ?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I'm very limited when it come to VM as I refuse to use it and therefore have little knowledge of it :/ By any chance, did anyone **with** admin privileges make any changes to the site?

Comment: No idea :( still comparing tables from working site and issue site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a MySQL issue. It may be:

- MySQL Bug
- MySQL Internal Inconsistency
- MySQL Load Restriction / Timeout

Since error is **MySQL server has gone away**, the connection is closed, and the MySQL process may have died. It's not a coding issue at Joomla level.

Check with your hosting support. If I have this error in my server, I run a check on the database to solve any inconsistency, and update MySQL to the latest version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is a strange thing on the same server another site with same joomla installation works fine. So if it is a Mysql issue it should be there too. But I am sure its not due to code bcoz both are working with same code. According to this situation I think both site have different DB size so Issue occurred site DB data is huge so the limit exceed.

Comment: Yes, mysql issues seem to be arbitrary. As we can't check the source code, we can't verify which is the real trigger. E.g. internal index structures. That's why a simple version update solves the issue in a magical way :-O

Comment: VirtueMart has also been very MySQL intensive in the past, the latest are still pretty heavy in the complexity of their queries.

Comment: Even if you have intensive queries, MySQL process does not die and go away, you just get a timeout.

Comment: @Anibal , Finally issue get fixed, Server Admin able to increase the mysql query execution time and issue get solved.